# does prettify not work with html?

Tags: html, prettify

I am trying to use prettify like this:

```
<code class="prettyprint lang-html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/myPlug/styles.css?v=1.0">
    <script src="js/myPlug.js"></script>
</code>
```

But no text is output on my page, do I have to manually convert every bracket, ie.

```
< to &lt;
```

and

```
> to &gt;
```

in order to use prettify with HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to convert `< to &lt;` and `> to &gt;` manually. Also to note that prettify works with HTML but for the brackets you have to change them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Basicially you just have to replace the opening tags but I think it is easier just to use a formatting service such as [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/).

The same problem occurred for me using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). Under Installation it says you have to replace them.

> PROBLEMS: Major issue with this method is that all right angle brackets must be HTML escaped, eg all < must be replaced with `&lt;` This will ensure correct rendering.

SyntaxHighlighter offers another method for highlighting your code by just including everything within a script tag using a CDATA block.

> The benefit of this method is ability to place virtually anything inside the CDATA without having to escape anything*, so this allows for a straight ‘cut and paste’ experience from your favorite text editor.